# How do I mix ö with \hl{} using [utf8x]{inputenc}

Tags: unicode, accents, soul

Say I'm writing about Schrödinger's cat. I would like to be able to put use `soul`'s `\hl{}` function to make the cat yellow.

This should work, but it doesn't:

```
% Minimum working example of UTF-8 ö problem
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

First try: Schr\"odinger's cat.

Second try: Schrödinger's cat.

Third try: \hl{Schr\"odinger's cat.}

Fourth try: \hl{Schrödinger's cat.}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))

(./mwe1.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-0.def)
! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.14 Fourth try: \hl{Schrödinger's cat.}

?
```

Clearly, I could use `\"o` everywhere instead of ö, but that seems like a real pain.

Comment: Load the `soulutf8` package

Comment: You don't need `utf8x`. Use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead.

Comment: @cfr or for any reasonably recent latex, don't load inputenc at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Really? It's automatic now?

Comment: @cfr yes  utf-8 is the  default encoding

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does loading `inputenc` with `utf8` do any harm? (I have this in pretty much everything somewhere and OverLeaf (was?) adding it by default to all document preambles.)

Comment: @cfr no it does no harm at all (and of course is needed if sharing documents with people on older systems, eg overleaf needs it still, I think)

Comment: Oh, good. I won't worry about it then. Thanks @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: All I did was move from `soul` to `soulutf8` and the problem went away.